# RegisterTempTable using dataset Spark Java

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, dataset

I have been using dataframe in my Java Spark Project (Spark version 1.6.1).
Now I am refactoring, trying to use the dataset in order to exploit the strong typed feature which comes with them.
In some part of the project I was using the following code:

```
dataframe.registerTempTable("table")
```

in order to use pure sql queries.

This kind of feature looks to be not present with dataset, I cannot find any similar method offered by them.

Can you confirm that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm that **no method** available in spark 1.6 for registering temp table or view using dataset.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html

These methods were introduced in spark 2.0.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [`createOrReplaceTempView`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#createOrReplaceTempView(java.lang.String)):

> public void createOrReplaceTempView(String viewName)
>
> Creates a local temporary view using the given name. The lifetime of this temporary view is tied to the SparkSession that was used to create this > Dataset.
>
> Parameters:
>
> viewName - (undocumented)
>
> Since:
>
> 2.0.0

Comment: As I said, I am using Spark 1.6.1 and cannot update.